# Array of flat objects, extract values of a all properties into single object of arrays

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to go from this:

```js
[{
  "uuid": 'oaiwngoiasofoi328',
  "property1": 3,
  "property2": 3,
  ...many
},
...many ]
```

to this:

```js
{
  "uuid": ['oaiwngoiasofoi328','829rh83hr9h9h29','mejieoainfoi',...],
  "property1": [3,3,2,...],
  "property2": [3,3,2,...],
  ...many
}
```

all the properties will be named the same in each object of the source array

maybe I could use a for loop with map... ??

Comment: Yes, you could. Did you try?

Comment: I was wondering if there is an existing example because I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to do this one. I spent the past 20mins trying to find something similar

Comment: I think you should start simple and try two nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

I've recreated your environment. I think it can help you.

Use `Array.reduce()` to reduce it to single object.

```js
const data = [
  {
    uuid: 'adadkljalkd',
    'property1': 3,
    'property2': 4,
  },
  {
    uuid: 'alkisdfj',
    'property1': 4,
    'property2': 5,
  },
  {
    uuid: 'klilkkll',
    'property1': 7,
    'property2': 8,
  }
];

const res = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
    acc[key].push(obj[key]);
  })
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: The original accumulator in the reduce function just needs to be an object instead of an array

Comment: edited the answer to initialize accumulator with object

Comment: Browser console sometimes cheats with you. It's my bad that array should not have a property. Thank you @Supercool.